# Locate a file regardless of Casing?

Tags: java, file, io

I'm working on a program. However, the program is that I'm on a Linux based operating system and it wants perfect case-match names for all of the files, and considering the artist has some named with Caps, some not, some have ".png" some are ".Png" and some are ".PNG", etc; this is becoming a very difficult task. There's a little over a thousand Sprites, or renaming them wouldn’t be a problem. This is for a 2D RPG Hobby project that I'm doing for learning, purposes that I've been working on for awhile now.

Anyhow, my question is if we can make the 'Compiler'(I think is the right way to word this) ignore the file ending character-casing? If I want to load the following items

- 1.jpg
- 2.Jpg
- 3.JPg
- 4.JPG
- 5.jpG

I would like to be able to do it in a single line.

Comment: Make a script that renames all the files to be the same (i.e. lowercase). That's the smart solution.

Answer (score 3):

You cannot make the compiler ignore case; this is a filesystem characteristic. Note that NTFS is case-insensitive but it is case-preserving nonetheless.

Using Java 7 you can use a `DirectoryStream.Filter<Path>` to collect the relevant paths; then rename if appropriate:

```
final DirectoryStream.Filter<Path> filter = new DirectoryStream.Filter<Path>()
{
    @Override
    public boolean accept(final Path entry)
    {
        return Files.isRegularFile(entry)
            && entry.getFileName().toString().toLowerCase().endsWith(".jpg");
    }
};

final List<Path> collected = new ArrayList<Path>();

try (
    final DirectoryStream<Path> entries = Files.newDirectoryStream(dir, filter);
) {
    for (final Path entry: entries)
        collected.add(entry);
}

Path dst;
String targetName;

for (final Path src: collected) {
    targetName = src.getFileName().toString().toLowerCase();
    dst = src.resolveSibling(targetName);
    if (!Files.isSameFile(src, dst))
        Files.move(src, dst, StandardCopyOption.ATOMIC_MOVE);
}
```

With Java 8 you would probably use `Files.walk()` and lambdas instead.

Comment: nice solution. I made a quick modification to the `accept()` method: `return matcher.matches(entry.getFileName());`. And added `private static final PathMatcher matcher = FileSystems.getDefault().getPathMatcher("regex:.*(?i:jpg|jpeg)");`. This makes it easy to check multiple extensions and case insensitive.

Answer (score 0):

If you know the exact directory for the file, you could use `File.list()` to get an `String[]` of all files in this directory. By iterating over those and using `toLowerCase()` on the filenames you can find your desired file.

```
String filename = "1.jpg";
String targetFilename = null;
File directory = new File("/some/path");
for(String maybeTargetName : directory.list()) {
    if(filename.equals(maybeTargetName.toLowerCase()) {
        targetFilename = maybeTargetName;
        break;
    }
}
if(targetFilename != null) {
    File targetFile = new File(directory, targetFilename);
}
```